# How does S3FS (or any other S3 FUSE filsystem) compare to AWS FSx for Lustre + S3

Tags: amazon-s3, distributed-filesystems, fuse, s3fs, lustre

I remember trying s3fs a year back, trying to use some S3 bucket as a FUSE filesystem. I remember it being quite laggy, especially when coupled with git operations on it (an oblivious system architect had a weird requirement like this).

Fast forward a few months, I discovered Lustre and AWS FSx for Lustre coupled with S3, which allegedly provides a very similar use case for it:

([aws fsx faq](https://aws.amazon.com/fsx/lustre/faqs/))

> Amazon FSx for Lustre works natively with Amazon S3, making it easy
>   for you process cloud data sets with high performance file systems.
>   When linked to an S3 bucket, an FSx for Lustre file system
>   transparently presents S3 objects as files and allows you to write
>   results back to S3.

So how does Lustre compare performance-wise with FUSE filesystems for S3 such as s3fs (and other like goofys)?

Thanks :)